# Ember CLI : Heroku build fails

Tags: javascript, heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm getting an error everytime I try to push to heroku via Heroku Buildpack for Ember CLI. I've read through the following with no success: https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli/issues/15
https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli/issues/51

Anyone know what could be going wrong?

remote: -----> Pruning cached bower dependencies not specified in bower.json

remote: -----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds

remote: -----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts

remote: bower loader.js#1.0.1         mismatch Version declared in the json (0.0.0) is different than the resolved one (1.0.1)

remote: bower ember-qunit#0.2.8   invalid-meta ember-qunit is missing "main" entry in bower.json

remote: bower ember-data#1.0.0-beta.12     invalid-meta ember-data is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json

remote: bower ember#1.10.0                 invalid-meta ember is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json

remote: bower                                 ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for ember-data

remote:

remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ember CLI app